# Set InfoPath Repeating table(DropDown List) field value through VSTA code

Tags: 2013, infopath, visual-studio-2012

I have followed below URL to construct repeating table dropdown list in infopath 2013([reference](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/programmatically-fill-populate-drop-down-list-box-infopath-2007.htm)).

Here,In my form loading event i have forming 4 rows with dropdown list and its working fine.But when comes to binding of collection of data to respective dropdown list, i am facing few difficulties.As per my requirement each row(DropDown List) should have different value rather common value.

For Example : My Collection of data's are Asia,Africa,South America,North America etc..Here Each row(DropDown List) should hold different value rather common value.In My Case its loading Common value like Asia..